# Ideals generated by a set in a ring without multiplicative unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is well known that in a ring $R$ with $1\neq 0$, the ideal generated by $S$ is $$I(S)=\{a_1 s_1 b_1+a_2 s_2 b_2+\dots+a_n s_n b_n: n\in\mathbb{N}, a_i, b_i\in R, s_i\in S\}.$$

Is there a similar expression for the ideal generated by a set in a ring without $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A,B\subseteq R$ define $AB$ as the set consisting of products of elements in $A$ and $B$ and sums thereof. Also let $\mathbb{Z}S$ denote the set of elements of the form $ns$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $s\in S$ and sums thereof.

Then, for a ring without unit, 
$$I(S)=\mathbb{Z}S+RS+SR+RSR$$
It's clear that this set is an ideal. Moreover it is clear that any ideal containing $S$ must contain this set.

Note that if a unit exists, then $\mathbb{Z}S\subseteq RS$; moreover $RS\subseteq RSR$ and $SR\subseteq RSR$. So $\mathbb{Z}S+RS+SR+RSR\subseteq RSR$ and $I(S)=RSR$.